# Python tqdm download progress with playwright

Tags: python, download, playwright-python

I have following code to download something (in this example it's a video).

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import func
import os, time, shutil
import requests
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def download():
    with page.expect_download() as download_info:
        page.click("text=720p (MP4")
        download = download_info.value
        with requests.get(download.url, stream=True) as r:

            # check header to get content length, in bytes
            total_length = int(r.headers.get("Content-Length"))

            # implement progress bar via tqdm
            with tqdm.wrapattr(r.raw, "read", total=total_length, desc="") as raw:

                # save the output to a file
                with open(f"{os.path.basename(r.url)}", 'wb') as output:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(raw, output)
                    download.save_as(os.path.join(func.report_folder_path, download.suggested_filename))

# initialize navigation
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="msedge", headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(accept_downloads=True)
    page = context.new_page()

    # go to canon s21 login
    print("Entering on download page")
    page.goto('https://www.jw.org/en/library/videos/#en/mediaitems/StudioFeatured/docid-702023003_1_VIDEO')
    page.wait_for_selector("text=Download")
    page.locator("text=Download").first.click()
    download()
    time.sleep(3)
    print('end')
```

I'm trying to implement a file download progress bar at the same time as the download is done by playwright. This code manages to download the file in the directory correctly and although it does not show a timeout error, it only ends the download function after the 30 seconds of the default timeout.

Another thing I noticed is that the download progress bar does not correctly show the real download status, i.e. it shows the download at 100% even though the real download file is still in progress.

Any idea how to fix these problems?